# gin inject and read config from async service

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-rpc, gwt-gin

i have got module and this module only read config from server via async callbacK:

```java
@Singleton
public class Config {

private ConnectionSettings connectionSettings;

@Inject
protected Config(final MainRPCAsync mainRpc) {  

      configureConnection(mainRpc);
}

private void configureConnection(MainRPCAsync mainRpc) {

    Log.debug("****Configure connection..");

    mainRpc.getConfig(new AsyncCallback<Configuration>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Configuration result) {
            Log.debug("-----------Get config");
                                 //initialize configuration settings

            });             

        }

    });
```

and next this class `Config` is injected to another module but when i need to get `configSettings` from that module i get only `null` ....

and in log console i read info that line `Log.debug("-----------Get config");` show info after all ...

Its possible be sure that connection settings will be initialized by rpc async before injection that class to another module ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need. I want to pass the result into a widget created with GIN.

**UPDATE**
I resolved with Assisted Injection. So, I create my widget into success method of async service, and I use the result for create my widget.